# C++: problems with strtok

Tags: c++

I need to break into words the text that the array of characters `s` holds. I attempted to do that with `strtok` but i get the `error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
char s[101];
char* p[100];
int main()
{
    cin.getline(s, 100, '\n');
    p = strtok(s, ' ');
    while (p) {
        p = strtok('\0', ' ');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why 'p' is  'char* p[100];' ?

Comment: You define `p` to be an array of 100 pointers to `char`. That's not what [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) returns. Also, to continue a [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) loop you should pass a null *pointer* as the first argument, not a string null terminator as a character (and this is the cause of the error you get).

Comment: @Rizwan in theory it should be an array of maximum 100 characters and I added the * thinking that it would help me fix the problem with strtok.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How should I define p?

Comment: @selbie I just tried that but I get the same error

Comment: Have you tried reading anything about `strtok`? Examples? The [reference I just linked to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)?

Comment: @JakeWright Often see this, new programmers get an error they don't understand, they attempt to fix it, and in the process make things worse (not surprising since they don't understand). They then post the even worse code instead of the original code. It would be better if you'd posted the original code as it's probably more correct and closer to what you understand.

Comment: 'How should I define p?' - `p` is a pointer, (that's why you called it p, right?) so just `char* p;`

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want:

```
int main()
{

    char s[101] = {};
    char* p = nullptr;
    cin.getline(s, 100, '\n');
    p = strtok(s, " ");
    while (p) {
        p = strtok(nullptr, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both parameters of `strtok()` are `char*` pointers, but you are trying to pass single `char` values instead, hence the error.

Also, `strtok()` returns a `char*`, which you are the trying to assign to a `char*[]` array, which will not work, either. Drop the array and just use a single pointer.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    char line[101];
    std::cin.getline(line, 100, '\n');
    char *word = strtok(line, " ");
    while (word) {
        // use word as needed...
        word = strtok(NULL, " "); // or nullptr in C++11 and later
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should not be using C semantics in C++ code. In this case, you should use `std::string` and `std::istringstream` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line, word;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> word) {
        // use word as needed...
    }
    return 0;
}
```